# Is there a way to set stroke width on a TimeSeries Flutter chart?

Tags: charts, dart, flutter

Using the [Charts package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/charts_flutter) is it possible to adjust the stroke width of a TimeSeries chart?

Looking through the documentation/[examples](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/line_charts/segments) I see that there's a `strokeWidthPxFn` exposed for line charts but I don't see it on timeSeries charts.

Here's my chart:

```
return new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
  seriesList,
  animate: animate,
  /// The following stroke width fn does not work with TimeSeries
  // strokedWidthPxFN: () => 2.0
  primaryMeasureAxis:
      new charts.NumericAxisSpec(renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec()),
  domainAxis: new charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
    showAxisLine: false,
    renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec(),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the stroke width, you have to use `charts.LineRendererConfig` which include a field `strokeWidthPx`

So add

```
defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(strokeWidthPx: 1),
```

after `seriesList,` to have a width stroke of 1.

So in the end, you should have something like this (for a stroke width of 5) (this is en extract from my working code):

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
...   
child: Container(
        height: 256.0,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
        child: charts.TimeSeriesChart(
            data,
            defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(strokeWidthPx: 5),
            animate: false,
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: I have updated the response with my full code, so you can compare your code with something which is working.